# Browsing methods in Flutter and Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

In other languages such as C# and Typescript I can select the method from a class in a dropdown to navigate to them quickly.

I'm using Android Studio with Flutter for the first time and I'm not seeing an option to do this. Is it supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I found that it's not supported in IntelliJ or Android Studio. The request has been out there for years and they never implemented it.

However, you can accomplish something similar by using the Structure tab on the left-hand side of Android studio.

It is in VSCode though.